# Calculate modulo in sh script

Tags: sh, modulo

I am working on an sh script in which I am in a WHILE loop where a variable gets incremented every iteration, and I'd like to save a file every five iterations.

What I'd normally do (say in C) would be to do an `if ( n % 5 == 0)` test, but I don't know whether that's possible here..?  If it isn't, does anyone have any ideas that would get the job done?

Cheers!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use bc when doing math in shell

```
if [ `echo "3 % 2" | bc` -eq 0 ]
```

Comment: Android Terminal has no `bc`

Comment: This is far obsolete; POSIX `sh` includes [arithmetic expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) since way back.

Answer (score 65):

If your sh really is sh and not just bash being run as sh then this will work just fine

```
if [ `expr $n % 5` -eq 0 ]
then
    # do something
fi
```

If your sh is really bash then put your test in `(( ))` like so

```
if (( $n % 5 == 0 ))
then
     # do something
fi
```

Comment: Note that modulo operation with negative numbers in bash returns only remainder, not mathematical modulo result.


This means, that while mathematically `-12 mod 10` is `8`, bash will calculate it as `-2`.

You can test it with simple `echo $((-12 % 10))` (`-2`) and compare it with python3 `python3 -c "print(-12 % 10)"` (`8`).

Comment: Second syntax much better, backticks are highly deprecated. Or `$(xxxxx)`.

Answer (score 14):

### Notes on the above answers

- Backticks are considered deprecated by now ([many further notes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126928/126755)), so I advise on switching to **`$(( ... ))`** or **`$( ... )`** constructs.
- Both `expr` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expr)), and `bc` ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)) are external commands, and as such would cause some measurable slowdown in more complex examples than mine or those above. Furthermore, there already is a way to easily **avoid** them (both). Also, they might not be available on all systems by default for instance.

---

### Suggested new solution

(Might be imperfect under certain conditions, I did test just basic scenarios.)

The simplest possible while portable and POSIX-ly correct code (no Bashisms ([Greg's Wiki on how to re-write Bash snippets to POSIX](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Bashism)); ([Wikipedia overview on POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX))) to test oddity (as an example) of a number would be as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
n=10
if [ $(( n % 2 )) -eq 0 ]; then
    printf '%s\n' "Number $n is Even"
else
    printf '%s\n' "Number $n is Odd"
fi
```

You can, of course, test **any modulo** there, not just if a number is even / odd.